# What is a target end point in reference to apigee?

Tags: apigee

Could any one explain me what is target end point with reference to apigee.
Is it related to virtual hosting?

I tried to go through apigee docs and community but didnt found anything useful

Answer (score 5):

A target endpoint is Apigee internal representation of "backend" functionality.

I.e. I have a backend service (a.k.a. the target endpoint) *myserver.com/getAccounts* which I point Apigee at and use its functionality (via Proxy Endpoints) as part of the API that Apigee provides.

Apigees official [description](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/reference/api-proxy-configuration-reference): "*TargetEndpoint is the outbound equivalent of the ProxyEndpoint. A TargetEndpoint functions as an HTTP client to a backend service or API*"

[See here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/understanding-routes)

[image]